# How are the Monero ARMv7 CLI binaries built?

Tags: compile, raspberry-pi

My goal is to set up a full Aeon node on a Raspberry Pi 3. I have been trying to compile the rebased Aeon code on it. After numerous attempts from scratch, the problem I encounter is that it errors out each time at different percentage of the build process, which suggest to me that the cause is not related to software dependencies but the environment instead, such as memory, swap space and so on. It feels like the Raspberry Pi 3 is severly underpowered to successfully accomplish this. Are the downloadable ARMv7 Monero builds cross-compiled? Wonder how they do that.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Monero's build instruction suggests that the swap size needs to be increased:

```
sudo /etc/init.d/dphys-swapfile stop  
sudo nano /etc/dphys-swapfile  
CONF_SWAPSIZE=1024  
sudo /etc/init.d/dphys-swapfile start
```

https://github.com/monero-project/monero#on-the-raspberry-pi